# Replace text returns error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to replace some text in a nested div. However the replace function returns `unrecognized expression`. I have tried numerous things but I can't get this to work.

```
 <div id="gui-checkout-shipment-methods">
   <div class="some-other-div">.... html content ....</div>                            
   <div class="gui-spacer"></div>
 * zzgl. Bei Lieferungen in das Nicht-EU-Ausland fallen zusätzliche Zölle, Steuern und Gebühren an
 </div>
```

So I'm trying to replace that text string `* zzgl. Bei Lieferungen in das Nicht-EU-Ausland fallen zusätzliche Zölle, Steuern und Gebühren an`

So what I tried is to select that text like so:

```
 var content = $('#gui-checkout-shipment-methods').contents().filter(function() {
   return this.nodeType == 3;
 }).text();
```

and then replacing that string with a new string like so:

```
 $(content).text(content.replace('* zzgl. Bei Lieferungen in das Nicht-EU-Ausland fallen zusätzliche Zölle, Steuern und Gebühren  ', 'zzgl. zusätzliche Zölle, Steuern und Gebühren, welche bei Lieferungen in das Nicht-EU-Ausland anfallen'));
```

This returns an error:

`Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: * zzgl. Bei Lieferungen in das Nicht-EU-Ausland fallen zusätzliche Zölle, Steuern und Gebühren an`

I think this has something to do with strings that are treated as html?? Or do I make a dumb mistake?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this will work `$(this).text($(this).text().replace())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.html()` instead:

```
var $myEl = $('#gui-checkout-shipment-methods');
$myEl.html($myEl.html().replace('* zzgl. Bei Lieferungen in das Nicht-EU-Ausland fallen zusätzliche Zölle, Steuern und Gebühren  ', 'zzgl. zusätzliche Zölle, Steuern und Gebühren, welche bei Lieferungen in das Nicht-EU-Ausland anfallen'));
```